# How to Fix 'Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: Cannot call set with 'definition' on an undefined object.'

Tags: javascript, ember.js

For my internship, I am a making a simple Ember app where I have users input text to be set as a flashcard's title and the flashcard's definition. This is all rendered on the webpage as a list.

When I input the new title for the flashcard, it updates the placeholder title. However, when I do this for the definition, I get this error:

```
Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: Cannot call set with 'definition' 
on an undefined object.
```

What I expect out of the setCardDefToNewDef action is to update the definition in the preexisting definition shown in my model. The way it should do this is by looking up the element using the id.

```
// app/controllers/about.js

    init() {
    this._super(...arguments);
    this.set('stashedNewTitlesById', {});
    this.set('stashedNewDefById', {});
  },

 addTitle: false,
 addDef: false,

 actions: {

   stashNewTitle(id, value) {
     this.stashedNewTitlesById[id] = value;
   },

   stashNewDef(idDef, valueDef){
     this.stashedNewDefById[idDef] = valueDef;
   },

   setCardTitleToNewTitle(id) {
     let card = this.model.find(card => id === card.id);
     let newTitle = this.stashedNewTitlesById[id]
     set(card, 'title', newTitle);
     let element = document.getElementById('input-card-new-title-' + id);
     element.value = '';
   },

   setCardDefToNewDef(idDef){
     let cardDef = this.model.find(cardDef => idDef === cardDef.id);
     let newDef = this.stashedNewDefById[idDef]
     set(cardDef, 'definition', newDef);
     let element = document.getElementById('input-card-new-def-' + idDef);
     element.valueDef = '';
   },

// app/routes/about.js

 export default Route.extend({
  model() {
    return [{
    id: 1,
    title: 'What is a route',
    definition: 'a different page on your website'
  }, {
    id: 2,
    title: 'use _super()',
    definition: 'Overriding parent class methods'
  }, {
    id: 4,
    title: 'What is .hbs?',
    definition: 'Handlebards file extension'
  }];
}
});

// app/templates/about.hbs

<ul>
  {{#each this.model as |card index|}}
    <div class="">
      current title: {{card.title}}
      <div class="">
        new title:
        <br>
        <input
          id={{concat "input-card-new-title-" card.id}}
          type="text"
          onchange={{action
            (action "stashNewTitle" card.id)
            value="target.value"
          }}
        />
          <button {{action "setCardTitleToNewTitle" card.id}}>
            update title
          </button>
          <br>
          current definition: {{card.definition}}
          <br>
          new definition:
          <br>
          <input
            id={{concat "input-card-new-def-" cardDef.id}}
            type="text"
            onchange ={{action
            (action "stashNewDef" cardDef.id)
            valueDef="target.valueDef"
        }}
        />
        <button {{action "setCardDefToNewDef" cardDef.id}} >
          update definition
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

Comment: sounds like find is not finding the element

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! cardDef is probably not defined in setCardDefToNewDef after the first line.

Answer (score 3):

Ola Ericka  thanks for your question! Also thanks for giving the source code, I was able to recreate your problem locally and have found the problem

So I'm going to start off with showing the code and then I'll go into a bit of an explanation. Firstly, I've made no change to your route file so I'm going to ignore that for now.

Here is the controller:

```js
import Controller from '@ember/controller';
import { set } from '@ember/object';

export default Controller.extend({
  init() {
    this._super(...arguments);
    this.set('stashedNewTitlesById', {});
    this.set('stashedNewDefById', {});
  },

  addTitle: false,
  addDef: false,

  actions: {
    stashNewTitle(id, value) {
      this.stashedNewTitlesById[id] = value;
    },

    stashNewDef(idDef, value) {
      this.stashedNewDefById[idDef] = value;
    },

    setCardTitleToNewTitle(id) {
      let card = this.model.find(card => id === card.id);
      let newTitle = this.stashedNewTitlesById[id]
      set(card, 'title', newTitle);
      let element = document.getElementById('input-card-new-title-' + id);
      element.value = '';
    },

    setCardDefToNewDef(id) {
      let cardDef = this.model.find(card => id === card.id);
      let newDef = this.stashedNewDefById[id]
      set(cardDef, 'definition', newDef);
      let element = document.getElementById('input-card-new-def-' + id);
      element.valueDef = '';
    },
  }
});
```

And here is the updated template:

```html
<ul>
  {{#each this.model as |card index|}}
    <div class="">
      current title: {{card.title}}
      <div class="">
        new title:
        <br>
        <input
          id={{concat "input-card-new-title-" card.id}}
          type="text"
          onchange={{action
            (action "stashNewTitle" card.id)
            value="target.value"
          }}
        />
          <button {{action "setCardTitleToNewTitle" card.id}}>
            update title
          </button>
          <br>
          current definition: {{card.definition}}
          <br>
          new definition:
          <br>
          <input
            id={{concat "input-card-new-def-" card.id}}
            type="text"
            onchange={{action
              (action "stashNewDef" card.id)
              value="target.value"
            }}
        />
        <button {{action "setCardDefToNewDef" card.id}} >
          update definition
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

The main difference that you will notice is that I've reused the same variable names for card (instead of doing cardDef) just to keep the code consistent and not to confuse myself  In once case this actually caused a problem because you were setting `valueDef="target.valueDef"` which won't actually work. You need to set it as `value="target.value"` because that is what the DOM API is expecting (not actually anything to do with Ember right here).

You will probably notice some other differences between your code and mine but they are probably only formatting. Let me know if you have any more questions about it.

Now that we have solved the acute issue I am wondering what you're trying to achieve here?  is all this "stashedNewTitlesById" just a way to stop you from dynamically updating the original model? If so then there might be a slightly easier way to do it  I'm happy to go into it in more detail but since I have already answered your question I'm not sure this is the right forum... Have you joined the [Ember Community Discord](https://emberjs.com/community) yet? If you have then reach out to me there, my nickname is @real_ate and I can help you improve this code sample.